# RxSwift how to skip map depending on previous result?

Tags: rx-swift

I am trying to download some json, parse it, check some information in the json and depending one the result continue processing or not.

What's the most RxSwift idiomatic way of doing this?

```
        URLSession.shared.rx
            .data(request:request)
            .observe(on: ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))
            .flatMap(parseJson) // into ModelObject
            .flatMap(checkModel) // on some condition is there any way to jump into the onCompleted block? if the condition is false then execute processObject
            .map(processObject)
            .subscribe(
                onError: { error in
                print("error: \(error)")
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("Completed with no error")
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

where `parseJson`is something like:

```
func parseJson(_ data: Data) -> Single<ModelObject>
```

`checkModel` does some checking and if some conditions are fullfilled should complete the sequence without ending in `processObject`

```
func checkModel(_ modelObject: ModelObject) -> Single<ModelObject> {
  //probably single is not what I want here
}
```

And finally `processObject`

```
func processObject(_ modelObject: ModelObject) -> Completable {
}
```

Comment: It feels weird that `parseJson` and `checkModel` return any sort of Observable at all. Are there side effects in them? Could they be converted into regular functions?

Comment: And `processObject` feels like it should be in the subscribe rather than in a map. I'm basing all this just on the names of the functions of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a tough question to answer because on the one hand you ask a bog simple question about skipping a `map` while on the other hand you ask for "most RxSwift idiomatic way of doing this," which would require more changes than simply jumping the `map`.

If I just answer the basic question. The solution would be to have `checkModel` return a Maybe rather than a Single.

---

Looking at this code from a "make it more idiomatic" perspective, a few more changes need to take place. A lot of what I'm about to say comes from assumptions based on the names of the functions and expectations as to what you are trying to accomplish. I will try to call out those assumptions as I go along...

The `.observe(on: ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background))` is likely not necessary. URLSession already emits on the background.

The `parseJson` function probably should *not* return an Observable type at all. It should just return a `ModelObject`. This assumes that the function is pure; that it doesn't perform any side effect and merely transforms a Data into a ModelObject.

```
func parseJson(_ data: Data) throws -> ModelObject
```

The `checkModel` function should probably *not* return an Observable type. This really sounds like it should return a Bool and be used to filter the model objects that don't need further processing out. Here I'm assuming again that the function is pure, it doesn't perform any side-effect, it just checks the model.

```
func checkModel(_ modelObject: ModelObject) -> Bool
```

Lastly, the `processObject` function presumably has side effects. It's likely a consumer of data and therefore shouldn't return anything at all (i.e., it should return Void.)

```
func processObject(_ modelObject: ModelObject)
```

**Udpdate:** In your comments you say you want to end with a Completable. Even so, I would not want this function to return a completable because that would make it lazy and thus require you to subscribe even when you just want to call it for its effects.

You can create a generic `wrap` operator to make any side-effecting function into a Completable:

```
extension Completable {
    static func wrap<T>(_ fn: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> (T) -> Completable {
        { element in
            fn(element)
            return Completable.empty()
        }
    }
}
```

If the above functions are adjusted as discussed above, then the Observable chain becomes:

```
let getAndProcess = URLSession.shared.rx.data(request:request)
    .map(parseJson)
    .filter(checkModel)
    .flatMap(Completable.wrap(processObject))
    .asCompletable()
```

The above will produce a Completable that will execute the flow every time it's subscribed to.

By setting things up this way, you will find that your base functions are far easier to test. You don't need any special infrastructure, not even RxText to make sure they are correct. Also, it is clear this way that `parseJson` and `checkModel` aren't performing any side effects.

The idea is to have a "Functional Core, Imperative Shell". The imperative bits (in this case the data request and the processing) are moved out to the edges while the core of the subscription is kept purely functional and easy to test/understand.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, lots of valuable tips! I need the whole thing to be completable, hence my subscrition to `onComplete` and the reasong to make `processObject` return a `Completable`, because it can complete the processing succesfully or fail. But even if processign si not needed, I need an event about "I am done" once `checkModel` decides to skip the processing. Obviously I am trying to do this with a single `onCompleted` branch to avoid any kind of subscritions piramyd and make things more readable.

Comment: I tried with a Maybe as you suggested and doing `maybe(.completed)` just jumps to my `onCompleted` subscrition, skiping `processObject`.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your need for the chain to return a Completable.